# Improper stacktrace from dynamically-constructed function in Nashorn

Tags: javascript, java, stack-trace, nashorn

I have the following code:

```
var f = (function() {
    return function foo() {
        try {
            throw new Error();
        } catch(e) {
            print(e.stack);
        }
    }
})();
```

When I call the function (in `jjs`), I get the following stacktrace as expected
(mostly; I was expecting `foo` instead of `f$foo`).

```
Error
        at f$foo (<shell>:1)
        at <program> (<shell>:1)
```

However, if I dynamically construct the function as follows:

```
var f = new Function([], "return function foo() { try { throw new Error();
} catch(e) { print(e.stack); } }")()
```

I get:

```
Error
        at <anonymous> (<function>:2)
        at <program> (<shell>:1)
```

Is there a reason for this discrepancy? Also, why is it `f$foo` instead of `foo` in the first case?

I am running jdk8u92. Running this on chrome gives me the expected stacktrace (with `foo` as the name of the function in both cases).